# PostMagging with spring boot java to mysql

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

the java spring boot code below represents a simple rest call to a java backend which performs an insert on a mysql database, but when it executes the rest call I have the error reported below, I can't define where the problem is when inserting in the mysql db, how do you solve the error represented by hibernate in console '? thank you

**Errore message hibernate:**

```
    "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: 
could not execute statement
```

**Controller:**

```
 @PostMapping("/newuser")
    public User createUser(@Valid @RequestBody User userDetails) {
        System.out.println("Sono nella creazione dell'utente");
        return userRepository.save(userDetails);
    }
```

**Model:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email_address", nullable = true)
    private String email;

    /**
     * Gets id.
     *
     * @return the id
     */
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * Sets id.
     *
     * @param id the id
     */
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * Gets first name.
     *
     * @return the first name
     */
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    /**
     * Sets first name.
     *
     * @param firstName the first name
     */
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    /**
     * Gets last name.
     *
     * @return the last name
     */
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    /**
     * Sets last name.
     *
     * @param lastName the last name
     */
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    /**
     * Gets email.
     *
     * @return the email
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     * Sets email.
     *
     * @param email the email
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    /**
     * Gets created at.
     *
     * @return the created at
     */

    /**
     * Sets created at.
     *
     * @param createdAt the created at
     */

    /**
     * Gets created by.
     *
     * @return the created by
     */


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                '}';
    }


}
```

**Repository**

```
import xxx.mode.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

/**
 * The interface User repository.
 *
 * @author xxxx
 */
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hibernate error you are getting:

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException
```

only means you have violated database constraints and looking into your **User** entity you have some constraints such as **firstName** and **lastName** should not be null. Hence, you are getting these errors the moment below line executes:

```
userRepository.save(userDetails);
```

Are you sure these fields are not empty?

Also you are using **@Valid** annotation yet I do not see any `javax.validation.constraints` used on your **User** entity thus, there is really no validation happening when your API got invoked. What I can recommend to you is:

1. Use `javax.validations` such as **@NotBlank(message = "First name is required"**) on your fields. This will throw a validation error the moment it hit your API and will not proceed to `userRepository.save(userDetails)`. Or better create a DTO class for your request body rather than using the entity - this is a code smell but I am guessing this is just for testing purposes.
2. Also, you can omit the **@Column** declaration on your `private long id` field since it is already annotated with **@Id**. Primary keys are already unique and cannot be modified.

Answer (score 0):

I guest firstName or lastName in the post object is null. Since you validate the object using the @Valid annotation, also make sure to add @NotNull on required fields to validate them during deserialization